# How to clear textbox after click of cancel button in confirm message box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

How can I clear my textboxes after I click on cancel button in confirm message box. My message box script is,(In web application). If we cannot perform with this script message, Refer me another one.

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "confirm", "confirm('Do you want to delete it ..!!');", true);
```

Comment: Try using a function to run your code, return True or False depending on your output, then use TextBox1.Text = string.Empty; if return is True

Comment: @SandySands, where??

Comment: @SandySands, In if condition??

Comment: Yes, in if.Do what Deepak Sharma (below) told you, but just add TextBox1.Text = string.Empty; to clear contents of the textBox

Comment: @SandySands, You mean like this :>ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "confirm", "if(confirm('Employee Details  Already Added In this ID. Do you want to override it ..!!')==false){document.getElementById(txtDate.Text) = string.Empty;}", true);

Comment: Yeah, why don't you give it a try.

Comment: @SandySands, I tried but text box not getting clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
confirm('Do you want to delete it ..!!')
```

it returns `true or false` on the basis of what button you have clicked..

better to write a separate function and include it in your JavaScript file and call like the above way you are doing..

else you have to write the whole code inline, but looks messy..

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "confirm", "" +
    "document.body.onload = function(){"+
      "if(confirm('Do you want to delete it ..!!')==false)" +
        "{" +
           "document.getElementById('myTextBox').value='';" +
        "}"+
      "}", true);
```

Comment: I am checking this with my project

Comment: Yes I changed 'myTextBox' to 'txtyDate'

Comment: shall we take the 'true or false' value in if condition??

Comment: false... 'TRUE' mean if accept OK else it will return FALSE,

Comment: no.. its not like that.. just use my given snippet.. its not the right way.. okay tell me r u using jquery?? or not??

Comment: and where you want this confirm box?? on button click??

Comment: I want this message box when I select dropdownlist value( I have did some select query under dropdown click event), No jquery just using this script messageblock

Comment: check my updated answer... just use this snippet in code behind onIndexChange event and it will prompt the confirm box and if you click 'Cancel' it will clear the `myTextBox` **(PASS your own text box id)**

Comment: Now no pop up message

Comment: then its surely the issue with you event or how you are binding this code from event or method.. as its working code from my working project..

Comment: i just paste this answer to my dropdown button click event and changed textbox id..Is it enough??

Comment: yes i think its enough.. if you say i can give u one aspx file, with on dropdown and one textbox in working condition.

Comment: try the below link to download the sample aspx file.. [MyTacTics.blogspot.com](http://mytactics.blogspot.in/p/downloadingpage.html?DownloadId=0Bxxluya0NKB2VDFyeTk1T2RXVTQ)

Answer (score 0):

```
   ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "confirm", "confirm('Do you want to delete it ..!!');", true) ? txtDate.text = string.Empty : txtdate1.text = string.Empty;
```

Comment: no..!! ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock() is a method returns void so can not apply these bool operation here..

Comment: @SandySands, when I apply this code, the txtDate.Text become empty before I clicked on yes or cancel button and txtDate1.Text showing error like 'Unreachable code detected'

Comment: I just edited the code, check once. @DeepakSharma Sorry, I didn't know.

Comment: @SandySands, It show red color under line with error 'Only assignemnt,call,increment,decrement and new object expressions can be used as statement'

Comment: @SandySands again u r doing the same thing, you are checking `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "confirm", "confirm('Do you want to delete it ..!!');", true)` as `true` but I told this method is void type so it doesn't return any value, so you can not compare with any value..

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo.

Comment: Could you please explain what does this code do? While it may solve the problem, code-only answer is not encouraged as it may confuse OP and future readers.

Comment: @SandySands you are confused between C# and JavaScript u r merging both together..better to google it and you will know what mistake u r doing still..